# Google Sheet calculation uses math result value instead of displaying value issue

Tags: math, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, decimal, rounding

I am not sure if I am on right platform to ask this question, if not please suggest.

I have this calculation in my sheet and it is correct: **39.13 * 84 = *3286.92***

But when I want to get **39.13** via formula I face with the next issue:

The formula looks like this:

Cell `A1 =(45 - 33.25) / 2` the result is **5.875**

Cell `A2 =(A1 + 33.25) * 84` the result is **3286.5** which is different to the result ***3286.92*** above.

The problem is that I used financial number formatting and on my Google sheets I see not **5.875**, but **5.88**. Which is correct if we say about visual as it rounded for me as for viewer but not for the sheet internally.

Looks like when a sheet does calculation it ignore visual formatting. Just assumption.

And it uses not displaying value **5.88** but **5.875** which is result of calculation in A1 cell above. I bet it works as I say.

Which is mathematically of course correct as well, but my question how can I make **A1** cell's result to be not just displayed as financial string but also to be used as **5.88** in next calculations?

Comment: You are right, it works exactly as you said it does. Adding explicit rounding to the formula in `A1` will do the trick. In other words, make `A1`'s display value match `A1`'s mathematical value.

Comment: @SergeyKalinichenko thank you for the comment! much appreciate it! got it, I just found =ROUND, ROUNDUP and DOWN formula but looks like it rounds and drops all the decimal values. For example 39.13 to just 39 or to 40. Any solution how to keep decimal numbers?

Comment: `ROUND` takes a second optional argument through which you tell it how many decimal places you wish to keep. Passing `2` should work in your case ([reference](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093440?hl=en))

Comment: @SergeyKalinichenko, wow, amazing thanks! this is what I actually wanted. Now I realised that I did all my calculation wrong all the time before your answer. Displaying option confuses a bit or maybe I just did not read manual how to use it, now I need to replace all the cells using this round function, thank you my friend!)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in A1 try:

```
=ROUND((45 - 33.25) / 2; 2)
```

you can replace `ROUND` to `ROUNDDOWN`, `ROUNDUP`, `MROUND` or `TRUNC` depending on how you want to treat decimals